# Problem getting value of Firestore document in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase cloud function to generate a restricted API key from Algolia whenever a document from the Users collection change.

The Algolia part works fine, but I do not get the userid value from the related Firestore document.

When I run this code, the first console.log throws the following error: *TypeError: change.data is not a function*.

I have checked the Firestore document field name and path.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

  //Generate a new API key when a user document is changed. (This will later be changed to trigger when a user document is created in Firestore)
   exports.generateAlgoliaAPIKey = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{user}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

      const userid = change.data().userid

      console.log(userid)

      const publicKey = client.generateSecuredApiKey(
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // A search key that you keep private
        {
          filters: `owninguser:${userid}`
        }
      );

      console.log("this is the new key: " + publicKey)


    });
```

Comment: Maybe exactly what it says. It's not a function, so try `change.data.userid` or `change.query.userid`

Comment: I tried change.data.userid and I now get the following error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userid'). The Firebase docs says to use change.data().propertyname which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the new data with: `change.after.data()` or previous data with: `change.before.data()`.

Check the documentation for trigger functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document).